# is there any way to get Dark mode in Pluto.jl

Tags: julia

I tried `Pluto` notebook and i love it, i'm new to `julia`, coming from python is there any way i can get dark mode in `pluto` or is there any defaults way to choose theme.

Comment: [Asked and answered](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-get-dark-mode-in-pluto-jl/47408/) at Julia's discourse board

Answer (score 1):

It is still a WIP, but here is the most current work at the time of this writing: https://github.com/Pocket-titan/DarkMode